# Asynctask within ListView ArrayAdapters getView / updating (already converted) View

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, adapter

just creating chat application. in chat window, i´m notifying the array adapter (of chat listview) after recieving messages. so far working fine, but now i need to download an image which is sent by other user to current user. this message has "[attachment]=xxx.png" in message text. in arrayadapter i check if messagetext contains [attachment].., then check if attachment is already downloaded / present in local storage. if no, i´m downloading attachment in asynctask (in getView of adapter). downloading works fine, but now in onPostExecute of download task, i want to load (downloaded) attachment into imageview of the convertview. it´s clear to me that the (converted) view is already returned before asynctask is finished. i´m not quite sure how to achieve here to update imageview in converted view / how to best handle notifying adapter about change.

here is my code (getView from ListView ArrayAdapter):

```
if (!file.exists()){

      AsyncTask_DownloadFile.DownloadFileTaskParams downloadFileTaskParams = new AsyncTask_DownloadFile.DownloadFileTaskParams(AppConfig.ATTACHMENT_URL, fileName, path, mContext);
      new DownloadTask(mContext).execute(downloadFileTaskParams);

}
```

and here AsyncTask onPostExecute:

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            mWakeLock.release();


            if (result == null) {

                Toast.makeText(context, "Download error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            else {

                final File file = new File(result);
                //Toast.makeText(context, "File downloaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                final ImageView iv_image = (ImageView) mconvertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_attachment);

                Glide.with(mContext)
                        .load(file)
                        .fitCenter()
                        .into(new SimpleTarget<GlideDrawable>() {

                            @Override
                            public void onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, GlideAnimation<? super GlideDrawable> glideAnimation) {

                                iv_image.setImageDrawable(resource);
                                iv_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                iv_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View v) {


                                        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, Activity_FullScreenImage.class);

                                        intent.putExtra("srcType", AppConfig.GALLERY_SRC_LOCAL);
                                        intent.putExtra("fileName", file);
                                        intent.putExtra("ArticleImageArray", "");
                                        intent.putExtra("position", 1);
                                        intent.putExtra("fullScreenLabel", "Label");
                                        intent.putExtra("chatPartnerId", chatPartnerId);
                                        mContext.startActivity(intent);

                                    }
                                });

                            }
                        });



            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your question is a bit too wordy. Improving the formatting and writing important parts in **bold** could improve answer probability.

Comment: Find image view before creating asynctask and send as parameter to asynctask construction in getView.

Comment: i tried to like that:

in getView call AsyncTask with:

`new DownloadTask(mContext,convertView).execute(downloadFileTaskParams);`

in OnPostExecute:

`final ImageView iv_image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_attachment);`

but still imageview is not updated after download

Comment: also tried with passing ImageView instead of convertedView, also not working. it seems as both views are not accessible any more more after converted view has been return, or am i wrong?